# Get notified when (custom) info window in GoogleMap v2 disappears on Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there any chance to find out, when a (custom) info window disappears (=is closed)?

Usually an info window disappears when another marker is clicked or when the space between the markers is clicked on the map. Until now I only see the opportunity to check by myself where the user has clicked (touched). But maybe there is some trick?

**Background:**

I am exchanging the marker bitmap when the info window is shown. As I want the info window to replace the marker, a 1x1 transparent pixel marker is shown. As soon as the info window disappears I want to put the original marker back again. In order to do that, I need to know when the info window is gone. Unfortunately there's no event listener for it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a callback as of the current version. Maybe it would be a good idea to add a feature request for OnInfoWindowVisibilityChangeListener on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2).

This would also cover the issue I put there: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5127.